# Computation is optimized only if variable updated in loop is local

Tags: c++, vectorization, compiler-optimization

For the following function, the code with optimizations is vectorized and the computation is performed in registers (the return value is returned in `eax`). Generated machine code is, e.g., here: https://godbolt.org/z/VQEBV4.

```
int sum(int *arr, int n) {
  int ret = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ret += arr[i];
  return ret;
}
```

However, if I make `ret` variable global (or, a parameter of type `int&`), the vectorization is not used and the compiler stores the updated `ret` in each iteration to memory. Machine code: https://godbolt.org/z/NAmX4t.

```
int ret = 0;

int sum(int *arr, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ret += arr[i];
  return ret;
}
```

I don't understand why the optimizations (vectorization/computations in registers) are prevented in the latter case. There is no threading, even the increments are not performed atomically. Moreover, this behavior seems to be consistent across compilers (GCC, Clang, Intel), so I believe there must be some reason for it.

Comment: Try making the variable `static` or member of an anonymous namespace. And remember that C++ compilers really only deal with [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Even if the compiler can see that there's nothing preventing certain optimizations in the current translation unit, it knows nothing about other translation units.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So, does the compiler need to suppose that the non-volatile non-atomic variable with external linkage might be accessible from multiple translation units _at the same time_?

Comment: I don't recall what the C++ specification says about the matter (or I would have written a proper answer) but since the compiler doesn't know anything else, that seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Aliasing. `arr` might be pointing to `ret` (and if you take it by `int&`, then `arr[i]` for some `i` might be designating the same object as `ret`).

Comment: @T.C. This seems to be the right cause: https://godbolt.org/z/324ou8. Could you, please, write it as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @DanielLangr: Of interest is: [Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)#Conflicts_with_optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `ret` is not local but global, `arr` might alias to `ret` reducing opportunity to optimize.

Comment: Experimental proof, local `ret` or `int* __restrict arr` produce same assembly: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nbXI-w)